# How to find decimal value of 1D binary array in numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a boolean numpy array like this,

```
>>> np_arr
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

and another 1D array like this,

```
>>> another_arr
array([128,  64,  32,  16,   8,   4,   2,   1])
```

I want to somehow do some *and* or *addition* to get only values where that 1 is present something like,

```
>>> np_arr
array([[128,64,32,8, 0, 0, 2, 1],
       [128,64,32,8, 0, 0, 2, 1],
         ....................
       [128,64,32,8, 0,4, 0, 0],
        .....................)
```

So then I can then sum them to find the binary value of the each 1D array in the 2D array..
Or is some simple way to get decimal value numpy array as result?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for multiplication.

Comment: Should those `8`s in your expected output be `16`s? And it sounds like you want [`numpy.packbits`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html). No need to multiply and sum.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq HAHAHA that was so simple... what is wrong with me sometimes :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is probably this:

```
import numpy as np


ar = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

np.packbits(ar, axis=-1)
```

Result:

```
array([[243],
       [243],
       [243],
       [243],
       [243],
       [244],
       [244],
       [244]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one way. It works because `numpy` broadcasts implicitly.

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

arr = np.array([128,  64,  32,  16,   8,   4,   2,   1])

arr2 = arr * mask

# array([[128,  64,  32,  16,   0,   0,   2,   1],
#        [128,  64,  32,  16,   0,   0,   2,   1],
#        [128,  64,  32,  16,   0,   0,   2,   1],
#        [128,  64,  32,  16,   0,   0,   2,   1],
#        [128,  64,  32,  16,   0,   0,   2,   1],
#        [128,  64,  32,  16,   0,   4,   0,   0],
#        [128,  64,  32,  16,   0,   4,   0,   0],
#        [128,  64,  32,  16,   0,   4,   0,   0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

here a quick and dirty way.

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])


a = np.array([17, 16, 12, 41, 0, 0, 5, 12])
for _ in ar:
    m = np.multiply(_, a)
    print(m)
```

here i've printed the values but you can append them in an array or use as you like.

Comment: Why is this better than a simple `ar*a`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson i guess for direct multiplication `ar*a` is the best solution but if you want to handle each row, do some operation on it (like sum) and then append it to an array then in my opinion this approach is better, in contrast to last part of the question

Comment: If you wanted to sum each row and accumulate the sums in an array you'd do `(ar * a).sum(axis=1)`. It's usually better to avoid explicit for loops when working with NumPy.